# AVCamBarcode sample code doesn't scan barcodes

Tags: ios, swift, barcode

I downloaded AVCamBarcode from 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamBarcode/Introduction/Intro.html
and installed on my iPod. As soon as I started the app and focused a barcode inside the preview view nothing happened. After I move and/or resize the preview view then it starts to scan and I see yellow bar with white barcode numbers. There is another issue - the scanned barcode has extra leading zero. This is minor problem because it's easy to trim this leading zero. However, expectation is that as soon as a user focuses a barcode inside a preview view, it should be scanned without extra user intervention to move/resize the preview view in order to make it work. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: similar issue on my side, let me know if you found the solution. Third party apps can detect the barcode but apple AVCamBarcode sample app is giving empty string to few bar codes.